# How to Calculate how many times an enzyme would cut a plasmid

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I'm a little confused as to how to figure out the formula needed to figure this out.

I have a plasmid that is 7.3Kb and am told that it is cut with an enzyme of 4bp. For some reason I thought that the formula needed to figure this out is:

(1/4)^4 x 7300

But it gives me such a low number that I don't think it's right so I'm just a little confused.

Comment: Do not work from formulae people give you. Work from logic. You will find it [here](https://www.mvls.gla.ac.uk/Teaching/SLS-FTB/ren.html), among other places.

Answer (score 1):

There are $4^4$ 4-cutters, which means that given a 4 cutter, you expect it to cut once every 256 bases on average. $7300/256 = 28.5$, so you expect 28 or 29 cut sites in the plasmid. This is identical to what you calculated.